# How is this possible? axios returns 200 status and data on Android tablet with no internet

Tags: android, react-native, http, axios, expo

I have a React Native app that polls my server every 15 seconds to retrieve data.

API response schema is:

```
{
 data: [{},{},...]
}
```

In testing how the app handles internet connectivity issues, I completely unplugged my modem and router, which the tablet was using for internet. I then logged the response from the axios call.

It seems to return a `200` status and the following `data`:

```
{
 data:[]
}
```

Function to hit API:

```
function getOrders({ token, params = {} }) {
  return axios.get(rootUrl + "/api/orders", {
    params: params,
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  })
}
```

Polling function declaration in React component:

```
const pollForOrders = async () => {
  try {
    const ordersReturned = await getOrders({
      token: mdToken,
      params: {
        page_size: 50,
        pickup_time_min: todayAtMidnight(),
        sort_by: "pickup_time",
      },
    })

    alert(
      `STATUS: ${ordersReturned.status}, isArray: ${Array.isArray(
        ordersReturned.data.data
      )}`
    )
    alert(
      `STATUS: ${ordersReturned.status}, LENGTH: ${ordersReturned.data.data.length}`
    )
  } catch (err) {
    pollFailures.current = pollFailures.current + 1
    if (pollFailures.current >= 4) {
      if (!err.response) {
        toggleIsBadConnection(true)
      } else alert(`Error polling: ${err}`)
    }
  }
}
```

Implementation of poll function in React component:

```
useInterval(pollForOrders, demoMode ? null : pollInterval)
```

Here are the alerts produced:

[image]
[image]

1. The tablet is not aware of any other networks.
2. Even if it was, I am 100% certain there was data on the server, so it wouldn't receive a response of an empty array.
3. This did *not* happen on the Android emulator (instead, an error was thrown and catch block handled accordingly). Only happens when running the app on an actual tablet.

**Two questions...**

1. Shouldn't it throw an error?
2. If it receives no response, how does it know to return a schema of `data: []`

Setup:

```
"axios": "^0.19.0",
"expo": "^34.0.1",
"react": "16.8.3",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-34.0.2.tar.gz"
```

Android Studio 4.0.1
Lenovo E8 tablet

Comment: it's impossible to tell what is happening without any code or any more information. try to isolate and reproduce the issue and share the code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. a shot in the dark - if your tablet is connected to your computer, `adb reverse` can make your localhost on your tablet map to your computer.

Comment: @brentvatne code added to help provide more context

Comment: is your rootUrl running at localhost? is your tablet plugged into whatever machine you are using for the actual developing?

Comment: @NathanShanko rootUrl is pointed at production, not localhost. Tablet is not plugged into the laptop but it is tunneling to the development server running on the machine. However, that connection is also broken once the wifi is shut off (app can continue to run just doesn't restart on code changes). The computer also uses the same wifi network so it doesn't have internet connection after shutoff either.